# Image Size Saving as 0kb in php -- yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I am using an extension named yii-facebook-opengraph which is used to login from facebook. And i am fetching the details in the backend and save them in the database. Here i am fetching the user image also, when i save the user image in a folder it saves the image but the size is 0kb.

the code i am using is below:

```
 $image = "http://graph.facebook.com/".$IsUser->social_key."/picture?type=normal";

    $img_file = file_get_contents($image);
    $file_loc = Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images/userimag/'.$IsUser->id.'.jpg';
    $file_handler=fopen($file_loc,'w');
    if(fwrite($file_handler,$img_file)==false){
          echo 'error';
    }
    fclose($file_handler);
    $model->profile_image = $IsUser->id.'.jpg';
    $model->save(false);
```

when i print the image url $image i get the image, but when i print $img_file it shows empty

Answer (score 1):

Use this for storing image file, if you have `allow_url_fopen` set to `true`

```
$url = "http://graph.facebook.com/".$IsUser->social_key."/picture?type=normal";
$img = Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images/userimag/'.$IsUser->id.'.jpg';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```